# Question on Proof of Splitting Lemma for Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

The setup of the question is as follows. Let the following be a short exact sequence of modules:

$$
0 \rightarrow A \xrightarrow{i} B \xrightarrow{p} C \rightarrow 0,
$$
and let $r: B\to A$ be a map such that $r \circ i = id_A$. We want to show that this implies the sequence splits, i.e., that $B\cong A \oplus C$.

This is essentially one part of the *splitting lemma* (for modules). The site nCatLab gives a [proof of this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+exact+sequence) (for abelian categories more generally), which goes as follows:

> Conversely, suppose we have a retract $r: B \rightarrow A$ of $i: A \rightarrow B$. Write $P: B \rightarrow A \rightarrow B$ for the corresponding idempotent.
> Then every element $b \in B$ can be decomposed as $b=(b-P(b))+P(b)$ hence with $b-P(b) \in \operatorname{ker}(r)$ and $P(b) \in \operatorname{im}(i)$. Moreover this decomposition is unique since if $b=i(a)$ while at the same time $r(b)=0$ then $0=r(i(a))=a$. This shows that $B \simeq \operatorname{im}(i) \oplus \operatorname{ker}(r)$ is a direct sum and that $i: A \rightarrow B$ is the canonical inclusion of $\operatorname{im}(i)$. By exactness it then follows that $\operatorname{ker}(r) \simeq \operatorname{im}(p)$ and hence that $B \simeq A \oplus C$ with the canonical inclusion and projection.

**Question.** I have a question about one step of this proof. They write "By exactness it then follows that $\operatorname{ker}(r) \simeq \operatorname{im}(p).$" My question is: how exactly (no pun intended!) does this statement follow from *exactness*?

My understanding of exactness of the sequence is just that $\operatorname{im}(i) = \operatorname{ker}(p)$ (along with $i$ being injective and $p$ being surjective). But how would exactness imply anything about $\operatorname{ker}(r)$?

Comment: The point is that $p$ restricted to the kernel of $r$ is an isomorphism, and the justification steps come from exactness. In other words, there's a map from the kernel of $r$ to the image of $p$ given by $b \mapsto p(b)$. This map is injective, since if $p(b) = 0$ then $b$ is in the kernel of $p$, hence the image of $i$ (by exactness), so $b = i(a)$ for some $a$. But then $0 = r(b) = r \circ i(a) = a$ which implies $b=0$. Similarly this map is surjective (maybe you can show this part yourself).

Comment: @kamills That helps, thanks. So exactness is used in that step (but not directly), and the author of this particular proof just left out a lot of the details.